# How can I convert a std::string to int?

Tags: c++, string, integer

I want to convert a string to an int and I don't mean ASCII codes.

For a quick run-down, we are passed in an equation as a string. We are to break it down, format it correctly and solve the linear equations. Now, in saying that, I'm not able to convert a string to an int.

I know that the string will be in either the format (-5) or (25) etc. so it's definitely an int. But how do we extract that from a string?

One way I was thinking is running a for/while loop through the string, check for a digit, extract all the digits after that and then look to see if there was a leading '-', if there is, multiply the int by -1.

It seems a bit over complicated for such a small problem though. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `atoi()`?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+string+int++c%2B%2B

Comment: Have a look at boost::lexical_cast:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm

Comment: @Chad So you're recommending he use an entire library for something the language can do with standard libraries anyway?

Comment: Weirdly enough, its saying that "No matching function for call to 'atoi'? Going to guess it takes a char not a std::string?

Comment: @Brandon, if you have a `std::string` `myString`, and want to use `atoi`, then you want to say `atoi(myString.c_str())`.

Comment: @WinstonEwert - pointed mostly at the boost:lexical_cast suggestion(s) - note the wink ;)

Answer (score 1116, accepted):

In C++11 there are some nice new convert functions from `std::string` to a number type.

So instead of

```
atoi( str.c_str() )
```

you can use

```
std::stoi( str )
```

where `str` is your number as `std::string`.

There are version for all flavours of numbers:
`long stol(string)`, `float stof(string)`, `double stod(string)`,...
see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: For issues with std::stoi see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6154614/195527 : it will convert `"11x"` to integer `11`.

Comment: #include <stdlib.h>     /* atoi */

Comment: @CC That's also the behavior of atoi: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/ "The string can contain additional characters after those that form the integral number, which are ignored and have no effect on the behavior of this function."

Comment: Would you mind updating this answer with `from_chars` from C++17?  It is supposed to be orders of magnitude faster than `stoi`.

Comment: `stoi` should be preferred. See [Why shouldn't I use atoi()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Comment: Any idea why there is std::stoi and std::stoul, but no std::stou or std::stoui to convert a string to unsigned int? Only to unsigned long?

Comment: if returns zeo ??? you dont know if  the string was actually 0 or conversion error !

Comment: But what will you do if `std::stoi("not-a-num")`, this will case `core dumped`

Answer (score 110):

The possible options are described below:

**1. sscanf()**

```
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <string>

        int i;
        float f;
        double d;
        std::string str;

        // string -> integer
        if(sscanf(str.c_str(), "%d", &i) != 1)
            // error management

        // string -> float
        if(sscanf(str.c_str(), "%f", &f) != 1)
            // error management
    
        // string -> double 
        if(sscanf(str.c_str(), "%lf", &d) != 1)
            // error management
```

This is an error (also shown by cppcheck) because *"scanf without field width limits can crash with huge input data on some versions of libc"* (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292861/how-could-reading-numbers-using-sscanf-crash), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022468/scanf-cppcheck-warning)).

**2. std::sto*()**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

        int i;
        float f;
        double d;
        std::string str;

        try {
            // string -> integer
            int i = std::stoi(str);

            // string -> float
            float f = std::stof(str);

            // string -> double 
            double d = std::stod(str);
        } catch (...) {
            // error management
        }
```

This solution is short and elegant, but it is available only on on C++11 compliant compilers.

**3. sstreams**

```
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>

        int i;
        float f;
        double d;
        std::string str;

        // string -> integer
        std::istringstream ( str ) >> i;

        // string -> float
        std::istringstream ( str ) >> f;

        // string -> double 
        std::istringstream ( str ) >> d;

        // error management ??
```

However, with this solution is hard to distinguish between bad input (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c)).

**4. Boost's lexical_cast**

```
    #include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
    #include <string>

        std::string str;

        try {
            int i = boost::lexical_cast<int>( str.c_str());
            float f = boost::lexical_cast<int>( str.c_str());
            double d = boost::lexical_cast<int>( str.c_str());
            } catch( boost::bad_lexical_cast const& ) {
                // Error management
        }
```

However, this is just a wrapper of `sstream`, and the documentation suggests to use `sstream` for better error management (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c)).

**5. strto*()**

This solution is very long, due to error management, and it is described here. Since no function returns a plain int, a conversion is needed in case of integer (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425759/do-i-need-to-cast-the-result-of-strtol-to-int) for how this conversion can be achieved).

**6. Qt**

```
    #include <QString>
    #include <string>

        bool ok;
        std::string;

        int i = QString::fromStdString(str).toInt(&ok);
        if (!ok)
            // Error management
    
        float f = QString::fromStdString(str).toFloat(&ok);
        if (!ok)
            // Error management 

        double d = QString::fromStdString(str).toDouble(&ok);
        if (!ok)
    // Error management
```

**Conclusions**

Summing up, the best solution is C++11 `std::stoi()` or, as a second option, the use of Qt libraries. All other solutions are discouraged or buggy.

Comment: Beautiful summary, many thanks. May I suggest to add an initial comment suggesting the  final solution so that only people interested in the details keep reading?

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, also you forgot (or rather should add cause it's an old answer) from_chars

Comment: Don't use `sscanf`. It's a C API function, and the question is regarding C++. If you're planning to use `sscanf` then at least use `std::`.

Answer (score 69):

```
std::istringstream ss(thestring);
ss >> thevalue;
```

To be fully correct you'll want to check the error flags.

Comment: This will not extract `-5` from `(-5)`.

Comment: @Nawaz, are the parens actually there, or is that just how the OP is presenting his strings?

Comment: I don't know. I'm just pointing out the limitation of the approach.

Comment: @Nawaz, that's not really a limitation, more of preprocessing required to get rid of parens.

Comment: That is what is called limitation. It cannot directly operate on input.

Comment: @Nawaz, It also can't operate on the input "WERWER". I don't think the parens are actually part of his actual string and I don't think the fact that I don't parse them is relevant.

Comment: I said that because he used the word "extract" when he asked : `But how do we extract that from a string?`

Comment: @Nawaz, ok... I don't take the word that way but I see how you could.

Answer (score 57):

To be more exhaustive (and as it has been requested in comments), I add the solution given by C++17 using [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars).

```
std::string str = "10";
int number;
std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data()+str.size(), number);
```

If you want to check whether the conversion was successful:

```
std::string str = "10";
int number;
auto [ptr, ec] = std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data()+str.size(), number);
assert(ec == std::errc{});
// ptr points to chars after read number
```

Moreover, to compare the performance of all these solutions, see [this quick-bench link](https://quick-bench.com/q/GBzK53Gc-YSWpEA9XskSZLU963Y). `std::from_chars` is the fastest and `std::istringstream` is the slowest.

Comment: This is the most cleanest solution.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this also allows bases other than 10, a feature *not* provided by good old `atoi`.

Answer (score 52):

Use the [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) function to convert the string to an integer:

```
string a = "25";

int b = atoi(a.c_str());
```

Comment: Never ever use `atoi`.  `strtol` does everything `atoi` does, but better, and fails safely.

Comment: Expanding on @BenVoigt's comment: a big reason to avoid `atoi` is that it reports conversion failure solely by returning `0`!  `atoi` not so much fails unsafely as it _fails silently_.

Comment: @VainsteinK: Some failures are reported by returning `0`.  Others cause undefined behavior with `atoi`.  That makes it useless for validation of untrusted input.  https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/ERR07-C.+Prefer+functions+that+support+error+checking+over+equivalent+functions+that+don%27t

Answer (score 15):

#### 1. `std::stoi()`

```
std::string str = "10";
int number = std::stoi(str);
```

#### 2. String streams

```
std::string str = "10";
int number;
std::istringstream(str) >> number;
```

#### 3. `boost::lexical_cast`

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
std::string str = "10";
int number;

try
{
    number = boost::lexical_cast<int>(str);
    std::cout << number << std::endl;
}
catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast const &e) // Bad input
{
    std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
}
```

#### 4. `std::atoi()`

```
std::string str = "10";
int number = std::atoi(str.c_str());
```

#### 5. `sscanf()`

```
std::string str = "10";
int number;
if (sscanf(str .c_str(), "%d", &number) == 1)
{
    std::cout << number << '\n';
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Bad Input";
}
```

Answer (score 10):

What about [Boost.Lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)?

Here is their example:

> The following example treats command line arguments as a sequence of numeric data:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    using boost::lexical_cast;
    using boost::bad_lexical_cast;

    std::vector<short> args;

    while(*++argv)
    {
        try
        {
            args.push_back(lexical_cast<short>(*argv));
        }
        catch(bad_lexical_cast &)
        {
            args.push_back(0);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: The link is broken. Could you fix it?

Answer (score 7):

Admittedly, my solution wouldn't work for negative integers, but it will extract all positive integers from input text containing integers. It makes use of `numeric_only` locale:

```
int main() {
        int num;
        std::cin.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new numeric_only()));
        while ( std::cin >> num)
             std::cout << num << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Input text:

```
 the format (-5) or (25) etc... some text.. and then.. 7987...78hjh.hhjg9878
```

Output integers:

```
 5
25
7987
78
9878
```

The class `numeric_only` is defined as:

```
struct numeric_only: std::ctype<char> 
{
    numeric_only(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table()
    {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> 
            rc(std::ctype<char>::table_size,std::ctype_base::space);

        std::fill(&rc['0'], &rc[':'], std::ctype_base::digit);
        return &rc[0];
    }
};
```

Complete online demo : http://ideone.com/dRWSj

Answer (score 7):

C++ has evolved over time, and with it the methods to parse `int`s.
I will provide a summary in this answer.

*Note: the answer applies equally to `long`, `float`, and other arithmetic types.*

### Comparison

The following table compares all options (only C++ standard options, no third-party libraries) from most recent to least recent.

| Method | Error Handling | Pros & Cons |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [**std::from_chars**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) | [`std::from_chars_result`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars_result) (manual error handling) | ✔️ fast and zero overhead ✔️ supports ANY base as run-time argument ✔️ also works for floats, with a format of choice ❌ interface is not ergonomic ❌ no locale support |
| [**std::sto***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) family [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) | `std::invalid_argument` `std::out_of_range` (exceptions) | ✔️ simple interface ✔️ supports ANY base as run-time argument ✔️ also works for floats ✔️ no overhead in happy path ❌ inefficient if errors are common ❌ obscure name ❌ no locale support |
| [**std::istringstream**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) [c++98](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98) | `bool` flag, or [`stream.exceptions()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) | ✔️ universal method (for types with `>>` operator) ✔️ considers locale (e.g. can change base) ✔️ can detect different formats (e.g. `0x...`) ❌ slow, and high overhead of streams ❌ limited support for different bases |
| [**std::strto***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) family [c++98](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98) | [`std::errno`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno) (global flag, manual) | ✔️ small assembly output ✔️ small overhead in happy/sad path ✔️ supports ANY base as run-time argument ✔️ compatible with C ✔️ also works for floats ✔️ supports locale ✔️ can detect different formats if base is zero ❌ obscure name ❌ interface is not ergonomic |
| [**std::ato***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) family [c++98](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98) | zero indicates failure (manual error handling) | ✔️ small assembly output ✔️ simple interface ✔️ small overhead in happy/sad path ✔️ compatible with C ✔️ also works for floats ❌ obscure name ❌ for `int`, no support for bases, formats, etc. |
| [**std::sscanf**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) [c++98](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98) | `int` amount of arguments parsed (manual error handling) | ✔️ small assembly output ✔️ also works for floats ✔️can detect different formats (e.g. `0x...`) ✔️ compatible with C ❌ interface is not ergonomic ❌ no type safety, very bug-prone ❌ limited support for different bases |

##### Recommended Practice

- If you have a high performance application, then use `std::from_chars`, or `std::strto*` if not available.
  The overhead of exceptions in `std::sto*` or `std::istringstream` would be unacceptable.
- Otherwise, if you need C compatibility, use `std::strto*`.
- Otherwise, if exceptions are banned from your project, use `std::istringstream`.
- Otherwise, use `std::sto*`, or create a wrapper around `std::from_chars`.

Most of the special cases are unlikely, so **most of the time, use `std::stoi` or a `std::from_chars` wrapper**:

```cpp
// could be generalized with a template
bool parse_int(std::string_view str, int& out, int base = 10) {
    auto [ptr, err] = std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), out, base);
    return err == std::errc{};
}

std::string s = ...;
if (int x; parse_int(s, x)) {
    // x has been parsed :)
}
```

The advantage of such a wrapper is that you can always fall back onto other functions prior C++17 while always having the same interface:

```cpp
// alternative pre-C++17 version
bool parse_int(const std::string& str, int& out, int base = 10) {
    errno = 0;
    char* end = nullptr;
    out = std::strtol(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), &end, base);
    return str.data() != end && errno == 0;
}
```

If you don't care about that, you can also make `parse_int` return `std::optional<int>` instead of assigning a reference.

Answer (score 6):

In C++11 we can use **"stoi"** function to convert string into a int

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    string s1 = "16";
    string s2 = "9.49";
    string s3 = "1226";
 
    int num1 = stoi(s1);
    int num2 = stoi(s2);
    int num3 = stoi(s3);
 
    cout << "stoi(\"" << s1 << "\") is " << num1 << '\n';
    cout << "stoi(\"" << s2 << "\") is " << num2 << '\n';
    cout << "stoi(\"" << s3 << "\") is " << num3 << '\n';
 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's probably a bit of overkill, but 
`boost::lexical_cast<int>( theString )` should to the job
quite well.

Comment: A typo.  It should be simply `boost::lexical_cast<int>( theString )` (where `theString` is the name of the variable which contains the string you want to convert to `int`).

Answer (score 2):

Well, lot of answers, lot of possibilities. What I am missing here is some universal method that converts a string to different C++ integral types (short, int, long, bool, ...).
I came up with following solution:

```
#include<sstream>
#include<exception>
#include<string>
#include<type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T toIntegralType(const string &str) {
    static_assert(is_integral<T>::value, "Integral type required.");
    T ret;
    stringstream ss(str);
    ss >> ret;
    if ( to_string(ret) != str)
        throw invalid_argument("Can't convert " + str);
    return ret;
}
```

Here are examples of usage:

```
string str = "123";
int x = toIntegralType<int>(str); // x = 123

str = "123a";
x = toIntegralType<int>(str); // throws exception, because "123a" is not int

str = "1";
bool y = toIntegralType<bool>(str); // y is true
str = "0";
y = toIntegralType<bool>(str); // y is false
str = "00";
y = toIntegralType<bool>(str); // throws exception
```

Why not just use stringstream output operator to convert a string into an integral type?
Here is the answer:
Let's say a string contains a value that exceeds the limit for intended integral type. For examle, on Wndows 64 max int is 2147483647.
Let's assign to a string a value max int + 1: string str = "2147483648". 
Now, when converting the string to an int:

```
stringstream ss(str);
int x;
ss >> x;
```

x becomes 2147483647, what is definitely an error: string "2147483648" was not supposed to be converted to the int 2147483647. The provided function toIntegralType spots such errors and throws exception.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, you could use:

```
const std::wstring hex = L"0x13";
const std::wstring dec = L"19";

int ret;
if (StrToIntEx(hex.c_str(), STIF_SUPPORT_HEX, &ret)) {
    std::cout << ret << "\n";
}
if (StrToIntEx(dec.c_str(), STIF_SUPPORT_HEX, &ret)) {
    std::cout << ret << "\n";
}
```

`strtol`,`stringstream` need to specify the base if you need to interpret hexdecimal.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is really old but I think there's a better way of doing this

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

bool string_to_int(std::string value, int * result) {
  std::stringstream stream1, stream2;
  std::string stringednumber;
  int tempnumber;
  stream1 << value;
  stream1 >> tempnumber;
  stream2 << tempnumber;
  stream2 >> stringednumber;
  if (!value.compare(stringednumber)) {
    *result = tempnumber;
    return true;
  }
  else return false;
}
```

If I wrote the code right, this will return a boolean value that tells you if the string was a valid number, if false, it wasn't a number, if true it was a number and that number is now result, you would call this this way:

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
bool worked = string_to_int(input, &result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::stringstream`, here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
string r;
int main() {
    cin >> r;
    stringstream tmp(r);
    int s;
    tmp >> s;
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) is a built-in function that converts a string to an integer, assuming that the string begins with an integer representation.

Comment: Any time you think about `atoi`, use `strtol` instead.

Comment: Both atoi and strtol return 0 when no conversion is possible. So there's still validation required before using it. (Ben pointed this out above)

Answer (score 0):

From [`std::stoi()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/):

```
// stoi example
#include <iostream>   // std::cout
#include <string>     // std::string, std::stoi

int main ()
{
  std::string str_dec = "2001, A Space Odyssey";
  std::string str_hex = "40c3";
  std::string str_bin = "-10010110001";
  std::string str_auto = "0x7f";

  std::string::size_type sz;   // Alias of size_t

  int i_dec = std::stoi (str_dec,&sz);
  int i_hex = std::stoi (str_hex,nullptr,16);
  int i_bin = std::stoi (str_bin,nullptr,2);
  int i_auto = std::stoi (str_auto,nullptr,0);

  std::cout << str_dec << ": " << i_dec << " and [" << str_dec.substr(sz) << "]\n";
  std::cout << str_hex << ": " << i_hex << '\n';
  std::cout << str_bin << ": " << i_bin << '\n';
  std::cout << str_auto << ": " << i_auto << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2001, A Space Odyssey: 2001 and [, A Space Odyssey]

40c3:  16579

-10010110001: -1201

0x7f: 127
```

Answer (score 0):

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s="32";  //String
    int n=stoi(s);  //Convert to int
    cout << n + 1 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long long toll(string a) {
    long long ret = 0;
    bool minus = false;
    for (auto i : a) {
        if (i == '-') {
            minus = true;
            continue;
        }
        ret *= 10;
        ret += i-'0';
    }
    if (minus)
        ret *= -1;
    return ret;
}
```

Usage:

```
long long a = toll(string("-1234"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert from string representation to integer value, we can use std::stringstream.

if the value converted is out of range for integer data type, it returns INT_MIN or INT_MAX.

Also if the string value can’t be represented as an valid int data type, then 0 is returned.

```
#include 
#include 
#include 

int main() {

    std::string x = "50";
    int y;
    std::istringstream(x) >> y;
    std::cout << y << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
50

As per the above output, we can see it converted from string numbers to integer number.

Source and more at [string to int c++](http://www.tracedynamics.com/string-to-int-c-plus-plus)

Answer (score 0):

```
int stringToInt(std::string value) {
    if (value.length() == 0 || value.find(std::string("NULL")) != std::string::npos || value.find(std::string("null")) != std::string::npos) {
        return 0;
    }

    int i;
    std::stringstream stream1;
    stream1.clear();
    stream1.str(value);
    stream1 >> i;
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

error handling not done

```
int myatoti(string ip)
{
    int ret = 0;
    int sign = 1;
    if (ip[0] == '-')
    {
        ip.erase(0, 1);
        sign = -1;
    }
    int p = 0;
    for (auto it = ip.rbegin(); it != ip.rend(); it++)
    {
        int val = *it - 48;
        int hun = 1;
        for (int k = 0; k < p; k++)
        {
            hun *= 10;
        }
        ret += val * hun;
        p++;
        
    }


    return ret * sign;

}
```

Answer (score -2):

there is another easy way : suppose you have a character like `c='4'` therefore you can do one of these steps :

1st : int q

`q=(int) c ; (q is now 52 in ascii table ) .
q=q-48; remember that adding 48 to digits is their ascii code .`

the second way :

`q=c-'0'; the same , character '0' means 48`

Comment: The question is about converting from `string` to `int` rather than from `char` to `string`.

Comment: buggy and not matching the question

Answer (score -2):

One line version: `long n = strtol(s.c_str(), NULL, base);` .

(`s` is the string, and `base` is an `int` such as 2, 8, 10, 16.)

You can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14794138/8328786) for more details of `strtol`.

---

The core idea is to use [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) function, which is included in `cstdlib`.

Since `strtol` only handles with `char` array, we need to convert `string` to `char` array. You can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13294114/8328786).

An example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>   // string type
#include <bitset>   // bitset type used in the output

int main(){
    s = "1111000001011010";
    long t = strtol(s.c_str(), NULL, 2); // 2 is the base which parse the string

    cout << s << endl;
    cout << t << endl;
    cout << hex << t << endl;
    cout << bitset<16> (t) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

which will output:

```
1111000001011010
61530
f05a
1111000001011010
```

Answer (score -2):

I think that converting from `int` to `std::string` or vice versa needs some special functions like `std::stoi()`
but if you need to convert a `double` into a `string` use `to_string()` (NOT C#. C# is .ToString() not to_string())

Comment: `std::stoi` is already mentioned in multiple other answers, and the question is not asking about converting double to string.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

**If you wot hard code :)**

```cpp
bool strCanBeInt(std::string string){
    for (char n : string) {
        if (n != '0' && n != '1' && n != '2' && n != '3' && n != '4' && n != '5'
            && n != '6' && n != '7' && n != '8' && n != '9') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int strToInt(std::string string) {
    int integer = 0;
    int numInt;
    for (char n : string) {
        if(n == '0') numInt = 0;
        if(n == '1') numInt = 1;
        if(n == '2') numInt = 2;
        if(n == '3') numInt = 3;
        if(n == '4') numInt = 4;
        if(n == '5') numInt = 5;
        if(n == '6') numInt = 6;
        if(n == '7') numInt = 7;
        if(n == '8') numInt = 8;
        if(n == '9') numInt = 9;
        if (integer){
            integer *= 10;
        }
        integer += numInt;
    }
    return integer;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't handle overflows or negative numbers. The second function is very similar to `atoi`, not sure why write it by hand. Also, some things could be improved: don't pass strings by value, use standard functions more (the first function could be rewritten using something like `std::all_of` + `std::isdigit`).

Comment: This code is incredibly verbose. As the other comment says, you could eliminate `strCanBeInt` entirely and just use `isdigit` from `<ctype.h>`. Just use `n-'0'` instead of that massive `if` series.