# c++ converting string to int

Tags: c++, string, int

```
//sLine is the string
for(int l = 0; l < sLine.length(); l++)
{
    string sNumber;
    if(sLine[l] == '-')
    {   
        sNumber.push_back(sLine[l]);
        sNumber.push_back(sLine[l + 1]);
        l++;
    }
    else if(sLine[l] != '\t')
    {
        sNumber.push_back(sLine[l]);
    }
    const char* testing = sNumber.c_str();
    int num = atoi(testing);
    cout << num;
}
```

I have this for-loop which checks each character of the string and converts every number in this string to be a int. But for some reason, the atoi function is doing it twice so when I cout it, it displays it twice for some reason... Why is that?

example:
INPUT
3   3   -3  9   5
-8  -2  9   7   1
-7  8   4   4   -8
-9  -9  -1  -4  -8

OUTPUT
3030-309050
-80-20907010
-70804040-80
-90-90-10-40-80

Comment: `sNumber.push_back(sLine[l + 1]);` may access beyond the string end.

Comment: @Vlad But i've put that there because of negative numbers...

Comment: It's executing the entire loop twice.

Comment: Can you show an example of the output, for some input? And on an unrelated note, use `isdigit` instead of the check against `'\t'`, just in case. :)

Comment: `std::string s = "45"; int i = boost::lexical_cast<int>(s);` btw

Comment: @MooingDuck what? How? theres only 1 loop. when I do a cout on sNumber, its fine. Just after the convertion, it displays it twice or 0...

Comment: @Danny: I understand your intention, but nevertheless: imagine what is going to happen when `sLine` is just `-`.

Comment: can you put an example INPUT/OUTPUT to see more clearly what you want to do and the error?

Comment: editted my post to show input/output

Comment: Well, you output 0 when the current character is neither a digit not a `-`.

Comment: @Danny This snippet makes no sense. Can you show an expected input and desired output?

Comment: @jon I have editted my post to show what I've inputted and the output of it. I want the output to be the same as the input (for now). Basically, I just want to convert it from string to int, but when it does the convertion, it has the extra 0 in all characters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a std::string to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/how-can-i-convert-a-stdstring-to-int)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's displaying a zero for all nonrecognized characters, because `atoi` returns `0` when given a non-numeric string (like a space!)

However, what you want to do, is shockingly simple:

```
std::stringstream ss(sLine);
int num;
while(ss >> num) {
    cout << num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this:

```
const char* testing = sNumber.c_str();
int num = atoi(testing);
cout << num;
```

Below the last `}` in the code you pasted, i.e. out of the for-loop. Currently you get a separate printout for every character in `sLine` because it's executed on every iteration of the loop. (The last character in `sLine` may be a linefeed so this can occur even if you think you wrote only one digit.)

Edit: Also move the declaration of `sNumber` *above* the for-loop.

You may also want to change `if (sLine[l] == '-')` to `if (sLine[l] == '-' && (l + 1) < sLine.length())` so you don't access beyond the end of the string if the dash is the final character on the line.

You may also want to rename the variable `l` to something that looks less like a `1`. =)

You may also want to rethink if this is the right way to do this at all (usually if a simple thing gets this complicated, chances are you're doing it wrong).

Comment: sNumber would be out of scope there

Answer (score 0):

You output extra `0` for the characters which are not digits. The problem is that [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) returns 0 when it cannot convert the input, so your whitespaces are printed as zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a painful way to recreate the wheel. You'd be better off using a stringstream to parse this.

```
std::stringstream strm(sLine);
int num;
while(strm >> num)
{
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Please don't encourage the use `eof()` or `fail()` as loop conditions. Doing so almost always results in buggy code. Rather do `while ( strm >> num ) { ... } `. For a demonstration of the evil power of `eof()`: http://ideone.com/ZKa67