# how can i convert c++ str to int?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c++ converting string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014387/c-converting-string-to-int)

I have the user input 9 numbers in sequence. I need to convert the string numbers to an int

```
string num;
int num_int, product[10];

cout << "enter numbers";
cin >> num;

for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
   product[i] = num[i] * 5; //I need the int value of num*5
}
```

Comment: This has been asked, and answered, many times before.

Comment: If you want the user to enter a number, just have them enter a number.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: Are you sure you want `num[i]`? That accesses just a single character from `num`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way by far to convert to a string and back again is to use the conversion functions.

```
 std::string s="56";
 int i=std::stoi(s);
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

and back

```
 int i=56;
 std::string s=std::to_string(i);
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

of course if you are reading input you might as well do it then and there too

```
 int i;
 std::cin >> i;
```

Comment: Something to note is that std::to_string is a C++11 feature. Not all compliers have it.

Comment: @Caesar how long are we going to have to keep saying that for?

Comment: Until the average C++ program uses it.

Comment: @Caesar Nah, until free compilers on each prevalent OS support the majority of it, which is more or less now.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just read immediately to an integer?

```
int num;
cin >> num;
```

Comment: this is a very good answer but i need both variables, a string and an int

Comment: @user1082764 Why?  Why do you need a string?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to have two variables.  It's usual in C++ to convert on the fly, in the
input stream, without ever seeing the text as a string.  So you
can simply write:

```
int num;
std::vector< int > product( 10 );

std::cout << "enter number: ";
std::cin >> num;

...
```

Note that I've corrected the way you've declared the array as
well.  You wouldn't normally use `int product[10];` in C++.
(And you'd almost never define two variables on the same line,
even if the language allows it.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full sample:

```
//library you need to include
    #include <sstream>
    int main()
    {
        char* str = "1234";
        std::stringstream s_str( str );
        int i;
        s_str >> i;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you absolutely must use a `std::string` (for any other reason.. perhaps homework?) then you can use the `std::stringstream` object to convert it from a `std::string` to `int`.

```
std::stringstream strstream(num);
int iNum;
num >> iNum; //now iNum will have your integer
```

Alternatively, you can use the `atoi` function from C to help you with it

```
std::string st = "12345";
int i = atoi(st.c_str()); // and now, i will have the number 12345
```

So your program should look like:

```
vector<string> num;
string holder;
int num_int, product[10];

cout << "enter numbers";
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    cin >> holder;
    num.push_back(holder);
}
for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
   product[i] = atoi(num[i].c_str()) * 5; //I need the int value of num*5
}
```