# Convert std::string to integer

Tags: c++, string, int, atoi

I'm trying to convert a `std::string` stored in a `std::vector` to an integer and pass it to a function as a parameter.

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
vector <string> record;
functiontest(atoi(record[i].c_str));
```

My error is as follows:

```
error: argument of type ‘const char* (std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::)()const’ does not match ‘const char*’
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to *call* it, but there are many better methods than `atoi`.

Comment: Typo `record[i].c_str` -> `record[i].c_str()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a std::string to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/how-can-i-convert-a-stdstring-to-int)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

With C++11:

```
int value = std::stoi(record[i]);
```

Comment: Quite helpful. For lower than C++11, is there any solid example?

Comment: **Reader Beware:** If you aren't 100% sure the input to `std::stoi` will **always be a valid integer**, you'll need to set up a `try/catch` for `std::invalid_argument`.

Comment: And also for `std::out_of_range`.

Answer (score 11):

```
record[i].c_str
```

is not the same as

```
record[i].c_str()
```

You can actually get this from the error message: the function expects a `const char*`, but you're providing an argument of type `const char* (std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::)()const` which is a pointer to a member function of the class `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >` that returns a `const char*` and takes no arguments.

Comment: I can see how the other answer is better, but I don't think this one deserves a downvote...

Answer (score 11):

Use stringstream from standard library. It's cleaner and it's rather C++ than C.

```
int i3;
std::stringstream(record[i]) >> i3;
```

Comment: @BЈовић Very nice. For C++11 onward though

Comment: i guess it must be sloooow as any streams

Comment: @Kip9000 in my opinion it's a bad suggestion. `std::stoi` is much better to be used for conversion. it's much clear and much faster. i'm sorry i can't revert downvote as my vote is locked now.

Comment: @javapowered: That's for C++11 though... As it says in the comments, but before your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

functiontest(boost::lexical_cast<int>(record[i]));
```