# c++ When I cast a string to an int, the int is just a random number?

Tags: c++, string, int

So I have a function which edits the values, but I cout the values in main to see that it outputs 1309668848 and changes every time I run the program. (this isn't happening in the preprocessor). I have been struggling with this for a while and decided to come here for advice.

Here's the function.

```
void GetDahInt() {
    std::string NewValueS;
    getline(std::cin, NewValueS);
    NewValue = (int)NewValueS.c_str();
}
```

Comment: It is the address of that c-string.

Comment: I tried using cin as well to input NewValueS but it's still outputting huge random numbers

Comment: You need to think carefully about what `std::string::c_str()` returns.

Comment: @Till The dynamic address in decimal? So how would I convert it without it doing that.

Comment: do you know what [`c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) is? If you want to [convert a std::string to number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12628428/995714) why don't search for the way to do it?

Comment: are you trying to covert text representing a number into an int ?  Try out atoi function.

Comment: @alexm [atoi is not a good way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20583945/995714) in C++

Comment: I'm using stoi now

Comment: Why did some1 downvote me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
std::stoi( str )
```

> Discards any whitespace characters (as identified by calling isspace()) until the first non-whitespace character is found, then takes as many characters as possible to form a valid base-n (where n=base) integer number representation and converts them to an integer value.

Source :[Documentation of stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Answer (score 1):

`NewValueS.c_str()` returns a pointer to array of characters.
You are casting the pointer to int (get the memory address of c_str()).

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

> string::c_str
>   Get C string equivalent
>   Returns a pointer to an array that contains a null-terminated sequence of characters (i.e., a C-string) representing the current value of the string object.
>
> This array includes the same sequence of characters that make up the value of the string object plus an additional terminating null-character ('\0') at the end.

`NewValue = (int)NewValueS.c_str();` cast the address to string, and the address changes every time you execute your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like `std::stoi` (string to int), called like this:

```cpp
std::string str = ...;
int value = std::stoi(str);
```

The pros and cons of this option compared to others such as `std::stringstream` are discussed here:
[How to parse a string to an int in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c)

The reason your cast produces a "random" number is that `c_str` returns a pointer to the start of an array of `char`.

Casting from a `const char*` to an `int` is undefined behavior (these types may not even have the same size), but will likely produce a memory address that depends on where your `std::string` is allocated.