# Convert vector<string> * char to int

Tags: c++, integer, char

I need help in my following code and hope that you can help me through. All I wanted is to pass in INT type to setX() and setY(). However, there is no way for me to convert vector char* to int. Is there alternative to this?

```
template<class T>
vector<string> Delimiter(T inputString){
    int count=0;
    char str[inputString.length()];
    strcpy(str,inputString.c_str());
    char * pch;

    vector<string> returnContainer;

    printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
    pch = strtok (str,",[]");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        returnContainer.push_back(pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ,[]");
        count++;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<returnContainer.size(); i++){
    cout << "return:" << returnContainer[i] << endl;
    }
    return returnContainer;
}
```

//Main()

```
fileDataAfterFiltered = Delimiter(fileData[i]); // Delimiter (vector<string> type)

point2DObj[point2DCount].setX(fileDataAfterFiltered[1]); // error
point2DObj[point2DCount].setY(fileDataAfterFiltered[2]); // error
```

//Assn3.cpp:107:59: error: no matching function for call to ‘Point2D::setX(std::basic_string&)’

Comment: where are the implementations of `setX()` and `setY()`?

Comment: Your `setX` or `setY` needs to have an overload that takes `std::string&` because you're passing in an element of a `std::vector<std::string>`.  We don't know what overloads it has, cause you haven't posted that code.

Comment: Have a look at [the function atoi()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7664227/220636).

Comment: @TonyTheLion that's not correct, either in fact or in the advice. all he needs to do is convert a string to an int.

Comment: @john, then his question wasn't very clear.

Comment: T inputString looks to be defeating T. Where is 'T' being used?

Comment: @Bryan Wong. Why is Delimiter declared as a template? You aren't even using the templated type. Get rid of `template<class T>` and replace `T inputString` with `string inputString`.

Comment: Also `char str[inputString.length()];` is a bug, should be `char str[inputString.length() + 1];`. Don't forget that C strings require an extra `char` for the 'null terminator'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Delimiter()` returns a `vector<string>` and you give one of these strings to `setX()` and `setY()`, but both expect an integer parameter. You must convert the string to int

```
int x = atoi(fileDataAfterFiltered[1].c_str());
point2DObj[point2DCount].setX(x);
int y = atoi(fileDataAfterFiltered[2].c_str());
point2DObj[point2DCount].setY(y);
```

**But**: in C++ array and vector elements start at 0 *not* 1, so you might want to replace this with `fileDataAfterFiltered[0]` and `fileDataAfterFiltered[1]` respectively.

Comment: Hi @Olaf Dietsche,

I have tried 
int x = atoi(fileDataAfterFiltered[1]); and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

there's plenty of ways of converting string to int. boost::lexical_cast is one which will magically do the conversion you want. Otherwise you can use atoi (if you don't care about errors), or strtol (if you do).

```
point2DObj[point2DCount].setX(atoi(fileDataAfterFiltered[1].c_str()));
point2DObj[point2DCount].setX(boost::lexical_cast<int>(fileDataAfterFiltered[1]));
```

Comment: Sorry if the question is not phrase correctly. 

Yes, all I need was to convert vector<string> to int and point2DObj[point2DCount].setX(atoi(fileDataAfterFiltered[1].c_str())); works perfectly fine!

Comment: You mean [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html), right?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yes, thanks. not used it a lot! updated accordingly

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a C++11 compiler, function `std::stoi()` will do the trick:

```
point2DObj[point2DCount].setX(std::stoi(fileDataAfterFiltered[1]));
```

Otherwise you can use the old `atoi()`:

```
point2DObj[point2DCount].setX(atoi(fileDataAfterFiltered[1].c_str()));
```

Aside from this, your code has many other problems, but I hope you can fix them by yourself.