# Easiest way to convert string-of-integers to int

Tags: c++

I have a very long number with hundreds of digits which I have stored in a string.
Now, I want to read it into an integer/long digit-by-digit.

`long int strtol ( const char * str, char ** endptr, int base );` 
takes an **end-pointer**, but it doesn't seem like I can set it right, because it tries to read in all digits, and hence, returns `LONG_MAX`.

```
char str[]=
"70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586";

char *pEnd; //set pEnd to str[1]'s address how???
long num = strtol(str, &pEnd,  10);
cout << num << endl; //LONG_MAX
```

I thought of solutions like copying it to a new character array, and then applying `strtol` but that doesn't seem like the best way to do it.

So what would be the easiest/best way to do this?

Comment: Don't use the `endptr` in this way -- it's only for output. I suggest using something that's _not_ `strtol` if you actually want to extract individual digits. Like, um, casting to `char` and subtracting `'0'`!

Comment: That's not what the endptr argument in strtol does. Read the manual page again.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The solution shouldn't differ I think.

Comment: @Cthulhu: Let the answerer decide that! These are two different languages and often have very different solutions. It's preferred to ask a question about one or the other, according to which you're _actually_ using.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Edited tags. C++. :) But with char arrays, I still think it should be relevant to both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to read a single digit, you can simply use:

```
int digit = str[digitIndex] - '0';
```

This works, regardless of the character set used by the implementation, because the standard guarantees that the digits '0'-'9' will be represented by contiguous values.

The `endptr` parameter of `strtol` doesn't do what you think: It is used to return the position where the conversion stopped, not to tell the function where to stop.

If you want to convert a multi-digit substring of `str`, you can copy the required digits only to a new string, like this:

```
std::string partialStr(str+startIndex, numDigits);
```

and then convert it to an integer using [one of the methods here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/convert-string-to-int-c).

Comment: Oh damn. Forgot all about the ASCII values! Thanks. Any way to use strtol?

Comment: **If** I did want to read in more than one digit at a time, is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

converting a single digit to its int representation is easy, you'd e.g. do

```
int i = str[0] - '0';
```

For the first digit. So you just need to create an array of integer, iterate over the string and convert each digit, storing the result in the array of ints.

Answer (score 1):

The end pointer is an **output** from that strtol. It tells *you* where it stopped reading, not the other way around.

If you want to read an individual digit then just do this:

```
digit = str[0] - '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

If the base is 10, and `LENGTH` is the string Length, do:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*Prototype*/
long int intpow( int base, int exp);

int main(void)
{
    long int result = 0;
    int i, j = 0;
    char str[] = /* blah blah*/

    for( i = LENGHT - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        /* -48 because ASCII code. */
        result +=  ( str[ i ] - 48 ) * intpow( 10, j );
        j++;
    }
}

/* Recursive integer power function*/
long int intpow( int base, int exp)
{
    if( exp == 0)
      return 1;

    else
      return base * intpow( base, exp - 1);
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you use the `cmath` **pow** function? Also, aren't you missing the char to int conversion?

Comment: I know that i am editing, and pow function uses double parameters, he doesn't need that.

Comment: I'll be using something like this. +1. Haven't tested the above though ;)

Answer (score 1):

use std::transform if you want to convert not only one of the digits but all of them:

```
size_t N = sizeof(str) -1 ; //or strlen(str) if str is a pointer, not an array
std::vector<int> theInts(N); 
std::transform(str, str+N, begin(theInts), [](char* pc){ return *pc -'0'; });
```

Comment: The code isn't correct. **1.** it should be `str.size()`, not `sizeof(str)`, **2.** that `function` doesn't look right. But `std::transform` does have potential for converting multiple values, hence, +1.

Comment: **1.** In the original post it says `char str[] = "345335"` etc., so `str` is not a `std::string` but an array of chars that has no method `size()`. `sizeof(str)` will give the size of that array in bytes including the zero-delimiter, so I'll correct the code (`-1`). **2.** which `function` do you mean? If it's the fourth argument to `std::transform` that looks "not right" to you: it is a C++11 lambda, taking one parameter and returning a char.