# How to convert string like 0x0000 to int

Tags: c++, string, int, type-conversion

How do i convert string like 0x0000 to integer??? 
This code does not work(Func atof always return 0).

```
String  str = "0xffff";
(unsigned int)atof(str);
```

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what `String` is. Of course you might find the [related links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/convert-string-to-int-c?rq=1) to the right helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to C++ `std::stoi`, you can use `strtol` (or `strtoul` for unsigned) which works for C and C++:

```
int i = strtol(str, NULL, 0);
```

Last parameter 0 means auto-select base to be 8, 10 or 16, depending on how string looks like. For `0x` prefix, base 16 would be used. For `0` prefix, base 8 would be used. For other decimals, base 10 is tried.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `String` is `std::string`, you can use [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

```
std::string str("0xffff", 0, 0);
int i = std::stoi(str);
```