# How to convert string to int64_t?

Tags: c, unix, int64

How to convert program parameter from `argv` to `int64_t`? `atoi()` is suitable only for 32 bit integers.

Comment: On a platform where `int64_t` is the same as `long`, then the quick hacky way is to just use [`atol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi).

Comment: Using sscanf with a matching specifier for int64_t may provide a platform independent method.

Comment: Slightly pedantic point: what you're asking is not how to convert `char *` to `int64_t` (if you wanted that, a simple cast would be the answer) but instead how to convert a string pointed to by the `char *`, which represents a number in some human-oriented textual convention like a decimal string, to `int64_t`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A C99 conforming attempt.

[edit] employed @R. correction

```
// Note: Typical values of SCNd64 include "lld" and "ld".
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int64_t S64(const char *s) {
  int64_t i;
  char c ;
  int scanned = sscanf(s, "%" SCNd64 "%c", &i, &c);
  if (scanned == 1) return i;
  if (scanned > 1) {
    // TBD about extra data found
    return i;
    }
  // TBD failed to scan;  
  return 0;  
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc > 1) {
    int64_t i = S64(argv[1]);
    printf("%" SCNd64 "\n", i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the clever thought to use `sscanf`, but it's `SCNd64`, not `PRId64`, that you need. I'm also unclear on whether `sscanf` has to behave well on overflow.

Comment: @R..  I think the `scanf()` family is specified to work like `strtol()` family of functions.  In the latter, range errors cause `ERANGE` to be stored in `errno`. (C11 draft 7.8.2.3.3).  So an `errno` test could be incorporated.

Comment: @chux Are you sure? According to [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/basedefs/inttypes.h.html) `SCNd64` is for `scanf` and `PRId64` is for `printf`.

Comment: @chux: I can't find anywhere `scanf` is specified to behave like that. The specification for `scanf` doesn't even state any requirement for how the value to be determined is stored. It just specifies the expected format of the input and required type of the output, but nothing about the conversion procedure. This seems to be an oversight, but it leaves a lot of ambiguity in regards to error handling...

Comment: @R.. My suggestion that the `scanf()` family is specified to work like `strtol()` comes from  C11 Draft 7.21.6.2.12: "`d` Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as
expected for the subject sequence of the strtol function with the value 10 for the base argument … ".  My Eclipse C  Indigo Service Release 1 compiler does set `errno` to ERANGE via `scanf()`.  So at least 1 compiler does so.  Although `strtol()` sets `errno`, I, like you, see ambiguity in regards to `scanf()` error handling.  Maybe others may know?

Comment: @chux: The text you cited describes the input sequences that the conversion specifier matches, but not the manner in which it is converted. While the intent seems to be that the value is obtained as if the matching sequence were converted by `strtol`, that's not explicitly stated, and in fact there is no `strtol` variant corresponding to smaller-than-`long` conversions like `%d` or `%hd`.

Comment: So, if `%d` were converted as if by `strtol`, it's possible that overflow of `long` would not happen, but the result might not fit into `int`, in which case it's not at all clear what should happen. (Clamping like `strtol` does? Implementation-defined conversion like in C expressions? Error?)

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.21.6.2 **The `fscanf` function** ¶10 _…Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a `*`, the
result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following
the format argument that has not already received a conversion result. If this object
does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented
in the object, the behavior is undefined._  Thus `scanf()` has UB on overflow — also listed in Annex J.2 Undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 18):

There are a few ways to do it:

```
  strtoll(str, NULL, 10);
```

This is POSIX C99 compliant.

you can also use strtoimax; which has the following prototype:

```
 strtoimax(const char *str, char **endptr, int base);
```

This is nice because it will always work with the local intmax_t ... This is C99 and you need to include `<inttypes.h>`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yeah you are right, but the the cast is there as a hint to remind that if the OP wants to parse it that they can replace it with a pointer to a string that's all.

Comment: @AhmedMasud That's what the documentation is for. Or maybe a comment. Please don't put in superfluous casts, they're redundant, may even hide hide errors and **most importantly, they decrease readability.**

Comment: @Ahmed: Ah, fair enough.  Note that it's also probably worth mentioning that this approach assumes that `int64_t` is the same as `long long`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: It doesn't assume they're the same, just that `long long` is sufficiently large to store any value of `int64_t`, which is almost true but not quite. See my answer.

Comment: When the result is in range of `int64_t`, this method is OK.  When the result would be outside the range of `int64_t`, this approach needs unposted additional work to portable detect such problems.

Answer (score 5):

Users coming from a web search should also consider [`std::stoll`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

It doesn't strictly answer this original question efficiently for a `const char*` but many users will have a `std::string` anyways. If you don't care about efficiency you should get an implicit conversion (based on the user-defined conversion using the single-argument `std::string` constructor) to `std::string` even if you have a `const char*`.

It's simpler than [`std::strtoll`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) which will always require 3 arguments.

It should throw if the input is not a number, but see [these comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/how-can-i-convert-a-stdstring-to-int#comment50933722_7664227).

Comment: stoll is available since C++11

Answer (score 3):

[`strtoll`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoll/) converts it to a `long long` which is usually a 64-bit int.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this 100% portably is a little bit tricky. `long long` is required to be at least 64 bits, but need not necessarily be twos complement, so it might not be able to represent `-0x7fffffffffffffff-1`, and thus using `strtoll` could have a broken corner case. The same issue applies to `strtoimax`. What you could do instead is consume leading space (if you want to allow leading space) and check for the sign first, then use `strtoull` or `strtoumax`, either of which is required to support values up to the full positive range of `int64_t`. You can then apply the sign:

```
unsigned long long x = strtoull(s, 0, 0);
if (x > INT64_MAX || ...) goto error;
int64_t y = negative ? -(x-1)-1 : x;
```

This logic is written to avoid all overflow cases.

Comment: But to be fair I doubt `int64_t` is defined on any system with a signed representation different than two's complement. I also think that's one of the major reason for the exact-width integer types to be optional.

Comment: I thought POSIX required it, but in fact POSIX only requires 8, 16, and 32-bit exact-sized types. `int64_t` and `uint64_t` are optional on POSIX. So I agree `int64_t` is unlikely to exist on systems where `long` or `long long` isn't suitable.

Comment: Unclear how "logic is written to avoid all overflow cases".  `-(x-1)-1` or `-x` work the same as `x`  is an wide unsigned type.

Comment: @chux: I think I meant `-((int64_t)x-1)-1`. Does that make more sense?

Comment: `-((int64_t)x-1)-1` makes more sense, yet `(int64_t)x` is still signed integer overflow.  Perhaps `-1-((int64_t)-(x+1))`?

Comment: @chux: No; `x+1` could be greater than `INT64_MAX`, or could be zero, and in either case, `-(x+1)` is equal to `x+1`, and either gives you the wrong result or an implementation-defined conversion when you cast to `int64_t`. On the other hand, `(int64_t)x` is well-defined because the above line just tested that `x` is in the range of `int64_t`.

Comment: However it looks like my code is missing the logic to actually handle the `INT64_MIN` case right...

Comment: `x+1` is not greater than `INT64_MAX` as I, like you in your earlier comment was referring to the left half of `:`, (when `negative` is true - (`x<0`))  OTOH, perhasp I am missing the condition when `negative` is set.  IAC, good to work with you.

Comment: `int64_t y = x<0 ? -1-((int64_t)-(x+1)) : x;`

Comment: @chux: The intent is that `negative` is set based on whether you read a `'-'` character before the number. `x<0` is always false because it has unsigned type.

Comment: The more I look at it the more I think my answer just has major flaws that make it no better than using `strtoll`, and likely worse.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with a different int64 type, and I like the clean C++ style:

```
std::istringstream iss(argv[i]);
int64_t i64;
iss >> i64;
```

You may get an compile error: operartor<<... is not defined.

And I don't know what happens, if argv[i] contains "HALLO".

Comment: If the conversion fails (like with "HALLO") you will get 0. But the fail bit will also be set, so you should call iss.fail() to check that.

Answer (score 2):

> How to convert string to int64_t?

The simplest

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int64_t value = atoll(some_string);  // Lacks error checking.  UB on overflow.
```

Better

```
long long v = strtoll(s, NULL, 0);  // No reported errors, well defined on overflow.
```

Robust:  Create a helper function to detect all problems.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Return error flag
bool my_strtoi64(int64_t *value, const char *s) {
 // Maybe add a s==NULL, value==NULL checks.

  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  long long v = strtoll(s, &endptr, 0);

  // Optional code for future growth of `long long`
  #if LLONG_MIN < INT64_MIN || LLONG_MAX > INT64_MAX
  if (v < INT64_MIN) {
    v = INT64_MIN;
    errno = ERANGE;
  } else if (v > INT64_MAX) {
    v = INT64_MAX;
    errno = ERANGE;
  #endif

  *value = (int64_t) v;

  if (s == endptr) { // No conversion, v is 0
    return true;
  }
  if (errno == ERANGE) { // Out of range
    return true;
  }
  if (errno) { // Additional implementations specific errors
    return true;
  }
  while (isspace(*(unsigned char* )endptr)) { // skip trailing white-space
    endptr++;
  }
  if (*endptr) { // Non-numeric trailing text
    return true;
  }
  return false; // no error
}
```