# How to convert a large integer from a string to a uint64_t?

Tags: c++, string

I have a large integer stored as a string. I need to convert it into an integer (`uint64_t`). I tried `stoi()`, but it is crashing after throwing an instance of `std::out_of_range`.

The string has maximum of 64-bit integer value, max value of 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 (maximum for an unsigned long int).

How do I do this, other than (of course) manually?

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002969/how-to-convert-string-to-int64-t

Comment: @PaoloM, I don't quite understand.

Comment: @i_am_jorf, in [this](http://oceanai.mit.edu/ivpman/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Lab.MOOSProgramming) link, go to section 4.1

Comment: @Paolo M - I think you meant that you cannot fit EVERY integer number into 64 bits???

Comment: @franji1 Yes, but the OP has now edited the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as the string contains a number that is less than `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()`, then `std::stoull()` will do what you're expecting.

(The `std::stoull()` function is new in C++11.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `stringstream` to do this.  This is supported in C++98 (the `std::stoull()` function was added in C++11).

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

uint64_t string_to_uint64(string str) {
  stringstream stream(str);
  uint64_t result;
  stream >> result;
  return result;
}

int main() {
  string str = "1234567891234567";
  uint64_t val = string_to_uint64(str);
  cout << val;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: check out this: http://cpp.sh/3dvx5 .... somehow the return value is different from the input.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to use stringstreams:

```
unsigned long long val;
std::istringstream stream(inputstring);
stream >> val;
```

According to [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) there's at least an overload for `operator>>` for `unsigned long long`, which could be the same as `uint64_t`.

Otherwise you'll probably have to do it manually, e.g. split the string into handleable pieces, and join the results by multiplication with the right base.

---

To be sure I'd go with this for now:

```
unit64_t to_uint64(std::string const & in) {
  static_assert(sizeof(unsigned long long) == sizeof(uint64_t), "ull not large enough");
  unsigned long long val = 0;
  std::istringstream stream(in);
  stream >> val;
  return val;
}
```

Comment: check out this: http://cpp.sh/3d7ys .... somehow the return value is different from the input.