# convert an string(which is a char* not a string type) to an integer

Tags: c++

i want to convert two variables which are in type of char* to int in cpp

```
char* lower = "552"
char* higher = "882"
```

these two variables are number but in type of char* like "552" and i want to convert them to int like:

```
int e = 552 //which 552 is converted from char*
```

is CPP has a function to do this for me?

Comment: Was posting this really easier than typing this: `[c++] convert string to int` ?? Try [Convert string to int C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/convert-string-to-int-c). One of the many answers from that search.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/

```
#include <string>

void main ()
{
    char *lower = "552";
    int e = stoi(lower);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try sstream !

```
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
   sstream s;
   char * lower = "552";
   int i;
   s<<lower;
   s>>i;

}
```