# check whether the user input is integer or string using integer variable

Tags: c++, c

i need to check whether user has entered an integer like 1,15,-1 or a string like 2bda or 5afnd etc. It can easily be done by using a string of characters.

can it be done using an int variable in c or c++?

Comment: `2bda` - What if I like to use hex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `int` cannot store an arbitrary string of characters.

`int` is a signed integral type that holds values between some min and max value, depending on the implementation-defined size. There is no error state or error value built into the integer (unlike floating point types which have a Not a Number value, `NaN`). However, you can choose values that are invalid, commonly the min or max value, or a negative value if only positive values are expected. Then you can check for that value before you process. For example:

```
#include <climits> // for INT_MIN

bool is_valid( int value )
{
    return value != INT_MIN;
}

int get_value( const std::string& str_value )
{
    std::istringstream ss( str_value );
    int value;
    if( ss >> value )
        return value;
    else
        return INT_MIN;
}

void print_if_valid( int value )
{
    if( is_valid( value ) ) 
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "invalid" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int num1 = get_value( "2" );
    int num2 = get_value( "a" );

    print_if_valid( num1 );
    print_if_valid( num2 );

    return 0;
}
```

Note that with this solution, if the value is actually `INT_MIN` (if `int` is 32 bit than this will be -2147483648), it will still be treated as invalid even though it was a valid `int`.

Comment: yes it cannot store. i just need to know if can it detect.

Comment: @BrijVaid: You check if the conversion succeeded, not the value of the `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Read input as a string.  Attempt various parsings.

```
char buffer[100];
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
errno = 0;
char *endptr;
long i = strtol(buffer, &endptr, 10);
if (errno == 0 && *endptr == '\n') {
  Handle_Integer(i);
}
else {
  HandleInputAsString(buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use atoi or stoi function:
[Convert string to int C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/convert-string-to-int-c)

If the function stoi cannot convert the string to a int, then it throws an exception, in that case you can assume that it is a string.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion you could use [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/examples.html#boost_lexical_cast.examples.strings_to_numbers_conversion) to efficiently turn user input to numerical input:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::string input;
  std::getline(std::cin, input);
  int i(0);
  try {
    i = boost::lexical_cast<int>(input);
  } catch(const boost::bad_lexical_cast &) {
    std::cout << "Wrong Input!" << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. it is not possible to check the entered input is integer or string using `int` data type. Because when you use `int` variable to scan data `2bda` or `5try` like this, the first integer only will get stored in that variable. Remaining input are omitted, Because integer can't store string's.

Sample program-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int num1,num2,ret;
        printf("Enter the integer\n");
        scanf("%d",&num1);

        printf("%d\n",num1);
        return 0;
}
```

Test 1:

```
root@ubuntu:~/c/array/string# ./a.out 
Enter the integer
123
123
```

When you give integer as input you will get proper output.

Test 2:

```
root@ubuntu:~/c/array/string# ./a.out 
Enter the integer
2bda
2
```

It takes only first integer, Remaining are omitted. Results undefined.

Test 3:

```
root@ubuntu:~/c/array/string# ./a.out 
Enter the integer
bdas2
-1217114112
root@ubuntu:~/c/array/string#
```

If your input is pure string, its totally undefined behavior! so you can't do that.