# Reading numbers from file c++

Tags: c++

I want to read numbers from text file.
The file contains following numbers.

`3 5 7 9 20 25 30 40 55 56 57 60 62
1 4 7 11 14 25 44 47 55 57 100
-5 100 1000 1005
-12 1000 1001`

Space separates numbers.
I had to make some code to read this but the problem is that reading the numbers at the end of line are not correct and I don't know how to read them properly(Problem with CRLF chars);
Can someone help me with this?
Here is my code.

Header
base.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class L
{
    public:
    int value;
};

class t
{
public:
    L *line;
    t(){
        line = new L[10000];
    }
};

class baza
{
public:
    ifstream in;
    ofstream out;
    string lines;
    char word1[1] ;
    int wordint;
    char tab[255];
    int *tab2;

    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int ile;

    int multiplier;
    bool negative ;
    int negative;
    t *table;

    base();
};
```

Here are base.cpp

```
#include "base.h"

base::base()
{
    wordint=0;
    a=2000;
    b=0;
    tab2 =new int [a];
    x=0;
    y=0;
    z=0;

    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        tab2[i]=0;

    }
    multiplier=1;
    negative =false;
    negative1=-1;
    lines="0";
    ile=0;
    in.open("in.txt");   //open file

    do   
    {
        getline(in,lines);
        if(lines!="0")      //how many lines is in the file
        {
            ile++;
        }
    } while(in.eof()!=true);
    in.close();
    tablica =new t[ile];
    tab5 = new int[ile];
    in.open("in.txt");

    for(int i=0;i<ile;i++)
    {
        do
        {
            in.get(word1[0]);
            if(word1[0]==45)   // check if sign is negative
            {
                word1[0]=0;
                negative=true;
                in.get(word1[0]);
            }
            if(word1[0]!= 10)  //check if  not LF
            {
                if(word1[0]!=' ')  //check if not space
                {
                    tab[x]= word1[0];
                    x++;
                }
            }
            if(word1[0]==' ')  //if space then convert from char to int 
            {
                y=x-1;
                do {
                    word1[0]=tab[y];
                    wordint=atoi(word1);
                    wordint=wordint*multiplier;
                    tab2[z]=tab2[z]+wordint;
                    y--;
                    multiplier=multiplier*10;
                } while(y>=0);
                x=0;
                multiplier=1;
                if(negative==true)  //check if negative
                {
                    tab2[z]=tab2[z]*negative1;
                    negative=false;
                }
                z++;
                c=z;
                tab5[i]=c;
            }
            /**if(word1[0]== '10')  //its not work but same as above only check if LF
            {
                y=x-1;
                do{
                    word1[0]=tab[y];
                    wordint=atoi(word1);
                    wordint=wordint*multiplier;
                    cout<<"dupa";
                    tab2[z]=tab2[z]+wordint;
                    y--;
                    multiplier=multiplier*10;
                } while(y>=0);
                x=0;
                multiplier=1;
                if(negative==true)  //check if negative
                {
                    tab2[z]=tab2[z]*negative1;
                    negative=false;
                }
                z++;
                c=z;
                tab5[i]=c;
            }*/

        } while(word1[0]!=10);
        for(int j=0;j<z;j++)      //write to table
        {
            table[i].line[j].value=tab2[j];
            cout<< table[i].line[j].value<<endl;
            tab2[j]=0;
        }
        z=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to post a short, self-contained, compilable example http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should simply combine examples as below:

- First, read all lines of the file (using [Read file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/c-read-file-line-by-line))
- Then, split the strings you got (using [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c))
- Finally, convert each element into a number (using [Convert string to int C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/convert-string-to-int-c)).

Your code will look way smarter than what you posted and should work.

Comment: Btw the accepted answer given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c seems  to cause some heavy discussions in the comment section due to inefficiency and non-scalability.

Answer (score 4):

This will read all the numbers from the file into a `std::vector<int>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> read_numbers(string file_name)
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(file_name);
    vector<int> numbers;

    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        int num; 
        while(infile >> num)
        {
            numbers.push_back(num);
        }
    }

    return numbers;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you call directly the `istream::operator>>` on the file?