# Can't copy from char pointer to short

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a char pointer that holds the following information:

```
char* data = "22";
```

I want to copy it from the char into a short variable.
I have the following code:

```
short BinarySerializer::getMessageTypeID(char* data)
{
    short* messageTypeID;
    memcpy( messageTypeID, data, sizeof( messageTypeID ) );
    return *messageTypeID;
}
```

I don't know why, but when I'm printing it I get: 12850.

This is how I'm printing it:

```
short temp = msg->messageTypeID;
cout << "Message ID is: " << temp << endl;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"I want to copy it from the char into a short variable."_ No, you want to **convert** it to a `short` value most probably. That's a big difference.

Comment: No, I want to copy. because in the future I will have more data on the char array (pointer).

Comment: @ShaulZuarets So clarify please what exactly you expect to be output for `temp`.

Comment: I expect the output to be 22. Even if the char array is "22sdfsd".

Comment: @ShaulZuarets As mentioned _copying_ isn't the right approach to do so. You want to parse numbers from a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).

Comment: What I really want to do is to take a char array and extract from it short, int and some more variables. I thought memcpy is the right approach. I Would be glad to hear about more approaches.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at the memory, assuming size of short is twice the size of char (not always the case!):

char array with "22" string is in memory:

50 50

so basically

00110010 00110010

when you memcpy it to a short, you get a single number, consisting of two bytes:

00110010 00110010

which, translated to decimal, means 12850.

Now, I think you really want to convert the "22" ascii table into "22" value. In such case, you may refer to

[Convert string to int C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/convert-string-to-int-c)

In case you really need support for strings like "23123dsdwdwqdwqd" (which is rarely a case), you may copy a substring of required size and work on the substring.

Keep in mind that only thing guaranteed by C++ standard when it comes to variable sizes is that

```
sizeof(char) <= sizeof (short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)
```

So if you rely on the fact that `sizeof(short) = 2 * sizeof(char)` then you're not portable at all.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean something from the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstring>

struct BinarySerializer
{
    short getMessageTypeID( const char *data ) const;
    short getMessageTypeID1( const char *data ) const;
};

short BinarySerializer::getMessageTypeID( const char *data ) const
{
    short messageTypeID = 0;
    std::istringstream is( data );

    is >> messageTypeID;

    return messageTypeID;
}

short BinarySerializer::getMessageTypeID1( const char *data ) const
{
    short messageTypeID;

    messageTypeID = std::accumulate( data, data + std::strlen( data ), ( short)0,
                                     []( short acc, char c ) 
                                     { 
                                        return 10 * acc + ( c - '0' ); 
                                     } );

    return messageTypeID;
}

int main()
{
    const char *s = "22";

    std::cout << BinarySerializer().getMessageTypeID( s ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << BinarySerializer().getMessageTypeID1( s ) << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

```
22
22
```

If the data can look like `"22sdfsd"`. then you need to add code that will find the first non-digit value.

Also you could use function `std::strtol` and check whether the obtained value is in the range for values of type short.

For example (without checking whether the obtained value is valid for type short)

```
short BinarySerializer::getMessageTypeID( const char *data ) const
{
    short messageTypeID = 0;

    messageTypeID = ( short )strtol( data, nullptr, 10 );   

    return messageTypeID;
}
```