# How do I add command lines as numeric data without using the atof function?

Tags: c++

Is there a way I can avoid using the atof function? How can I convert a string to float?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double x = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<argc; i++)
    x += atof(argv[i]);
    cout<<x<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why would you want to avoid using a library function?

Comment: @Jack For example, because it's bad practice to use the aforementioned library function. It may exhibit undefined behavior if the input is inappropriate, it reduces the possibility of error handling, etc.

Comment: Just to note, the first element in the argv array is the executable name. You should start at index '1' for arguments passed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to int C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/convert-string-to-int-c)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stringstream`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {    
  int val;
  stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
  ss << "120";   
  ss >> val;    
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not `std::istringstream stream("120"); stream >> value;`?

Comment: @stefan while we are at it: `std::stringstream("120") >> value;`

Comment: Yes, I agree with you guys. I think I just try to write down the most standard one. While yours are more concise :)

Answer (score 0):

For converting a string to a floating-point number in C++, it's now (since the standardization of C++11) advisable to use [one of `std::stof`, `std::stod` and `std::strold`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) (where these functions had been added to the C++ standard library):

```
std::string s = "120.0";
float f = std::stof(s);
double d = std::stod(s);
long double ld = std::stold(s);
```

The primary reason to prefer these functions over those in the C standard library is safety:

1. they don't operate on raw pointers but string objects (that also leads to a minor improvement in convenience and readability: one does not have to call `c_str()` over and over again when working with `std::string`s); and
2. they don't exhibit undefined behavior when the conversion is impossible (they predictably throw well-documented exceptions instead).

Comment: *it's now advisable* by which authority and/or reason? And what do you mean with *now*? as opposed to when?

Comment: @Walter the reason is safety: 1. they don't operate on raw pointers but string objects (that also leads to a minor improvement in convenience and readability: one does not have to call `c_str()` over and over again); 2. and they don't exhibit undefined behavior when the conversion is impossible (they predictably throw well-documented exceptions instead). "Now" as opposed to before the existence and standardization of C++11 (where these functions had been added to the C++ standard library).

Comment: Great, so add this to your answer!

Comment: @Walter I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) to convert between written and numeric types in a way that's very idiomatic for C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double x = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++)
    x += boost::lexical_cast<float>(argv[i]);
    cout<<x<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```