# Passing std::string as parameter gives error - htons function

Tags: c++, c++11, c-strings

I'm working with sockets, but when I compile my program I get some errors.

This is my code:

```
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_port = htons(string); // here I get an error
inet_aton(str.c_str(),&address.sin_addr);
```

What I get is:

> cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits > >::value_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}’ to ‘uint16_t {aka short unsigned int}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘uint16_t htons(uint16_t)’

How can I solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The function `htons` says it takes a `uint16_t`, and you are passing it `string`. What is unclear about that?

Comment: @CoryKramer how can I make a conversion?

Comment: could use `std::stoi`, or a `stringstream` would probably be better because you're looking for a specific number of bits and unsigned

Comment: @RyanHaining I didn't found nothing on Internet about that :(. If you make an answer with an example, I can +1 it!

Comment: @orlow65 Really? [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/convert-string-to-int-c) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c)?

Comment: @CoryKramer I want to use a simple stream. `std::stoi` isn't better.

Comment: @orlow65 There are literally 7 examples of using streams to convert a string to an int if you bothered looking at the posts I linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your `std::string` to a `std::uint16_t`.  I'd recommend a [`stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)

```
std::istringstream ss(string); // maybe pick a different name
std::uint16_t port{};
ss >> port;
address.sin_port = htons(port);
```

Be sure to `#include <sstream>`

Comment: I get: `error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::ostringstream {aka std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char>}’ and ‘uint16_t {aka short unsigned int}’)`

Comment: Change `ostringstream` to `istringstream`.

Answer (score 0):

htons requires an uint16_t
which means you have to pass the port as integer, not as string

Comment: `integer` type doesn't exists in C++. And `int` != `uint`

Comment: @orlow65 - `integer` informally means _"some integral type"_, such as uint16_t, uint32_t, int64_t, etc. etc. Don't be pedantic when you're asking a very basic question, it's not a good look.

Comment: @orlow65 I even stated uint16_6 the line before. Excuse me for not typing it again 9 words later

Comment: @Useless his answer is misinterpretable. An `integer` formally is relevant an `int`, but `integer` doesn't exist as a type. `uint16_t` is not an integer, but an unsigned 16-bit integer.

Comment: uint16_t is an unsigned 16 bit integer, which still is an integer

Comment: @l3ck not technically.

Comment: how not? it's a generalisation

Comment: "Don't be pedantic" - how can you *possibly* not be pedantic, and be a programmer?  Pedantry is what programming is about!

Comment: @MartinBonner - Hah, perhaps! I feel this pedantry is misplaced though, and surely avoiding redundant repetition is also desirable?

Comment: @orlow65 - the answer is fine, so long as you understand `integer` is not a type, but a _kind of type_, which contains all of `{char, short, int, etc.}`, and their unsigned variants, and implicitly their bit-size-specific typedefs. See, for example [std::is_integral](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral). Since the answer already specified `uint16_t` once, and you can anyway read this in the documentation, I don't see what you're complaining about.