# Converting string array to int array in c++/cli

Tags: c++-cli

Haven't found an answer anywhere on how to convert a string array to int array.

```
for (int m=0; m<z; m++)
{
    rikiavimas(rekordininkai[m], i);
}

private: void rikiavimas(array<Int32>^ A, int j)
{
    A = gcnew array<Int32>(100);
}
```

My rekordininkai[m] is a string array. How can I get this to work?

Comment: What do you mean by converting a string array to int array? Are all thw strings in the string array integers?

Comment: Yes, all of them are integers.

Comment: Ugh, you did not get very far.  The `A` parameter should of course be an array of strings.  Use A->Length instead of 100.  Use Int32::Parse() to convert from a string to an int.  What the `j` parameter might mean is very hard to guess.  My crystal ball says that rekordininkai[m] is a string, not a string array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const int N = 100; // just an example

string arrayOfStrings[N];
int arrayOfIntegers[N];

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) cin >> arrayOfStrings[i];

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) arrayOfIntegers[i] = stoi(arrayOfStrings[i]);
```

You can read the documentation for [stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) for more details.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/convert-string-to-int-c) for additional methods.