# Arduino: Get Hex value from two decimal strings

Tags: c++, arduino, type-conversion

I would like to do a conversion but don't know how.

Originally I get a Hex value like `03 EE` which represents `1006`.
Now those data is represent in a String array and as decimals:

```
[0] = "3"
[1] = "238"
```

Whats the easiest way to get back to a decimal `1006` from this situation?

I do this on an Arduino with C++

Comment: well you need to apply the same algorithm backwards : convert each field into its hexadecimal string representation, concatenate all strings and convert the new string into its numerical hexadecimal representation

Comment: @Kai Just interesting: where do you get this string from?

Comment: It's from the CAN bus of my car. The string represents the engines current RPM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Arduino's `String` cannot process hex representations, you should do it manually or with another libraries (e.g. using `sprintf` from standard C library, if it is possible). Here is a manual way:

```
int decBytesToInt(const String &msByte, const String &lsByte)
{
    int res = 0;
    res |= (msByte.toInt() & 0xFF) << 8;
    res |= (lsByte.toInt() & 0xFF);
}
```

`msByte` and `lsByte` are most significant and least significant bytes decimal representations correspondingly.

Supposed that `int` is 16-bit, of course.

Comment: Hi. So how would I feed "3EE" to this function so it would return 1006?

Comment: @Kai, `int x = decBytesToInt("3", "238")`.

Comment: Thanks alot. I'll try it once I am near my Arduino board :)

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
const char* s[] = {"3", "238"};

int result = (std::stoi(std::string(s[0])) << 8)
          + std::stoi(std::string(s[1]));
std::cout << result;
```

Please note that I use `std::stoi`, if you don't like it, please see for more conversion possibilities at: [Convert string to int C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/convert-string-to-int-c)

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da8037d62110db1a)</kbd>