# Is it possible to pass input arguments to an executable in the command line

Tags: c++, cmd, command-line

let's say I have this c++ code which I compiled into an executable out.exe

```
int main(){   
   int a = 0;  
   cin>>a;

   if (a)    
      cout<<"done";  

   return 0;  
}
```

Normally I would execute it using the command line by typing its name, then it would wait for my input.

However, what I want it to pass the input in the same line that I am calling the executable like so:

```
out.exe 1
```

1 being the input so the program wouldn't wait for my input and directly outputs:

```
done
```

Comment: You can input an array of characters only.

Comment: What you're looking for is called "input stream redirection" or "input stream piping". I'm not sure how it works under windows, should be something like `echo 1 | out.exe`

Comment: There's also an option to use command-line arguments instead. If you'll update `main` signature to `int main(int argc, char** argv)`, `argv` will be a c-string array containing all arguments you've provided after `out.exe`, and `argc` would be their count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `int main(int argc, char **argv)` command line arguments `**argv`, and argument counter `argc` look in [*What does int argc, char *argv[] mean?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean).

The arguments are read as strings but you can easily convert them into the type you need, in this case `int`. *[How can I convert a std::string to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/how-can-i-convert-a-stdstring-to-int)*