# c++ error when using greater than equal to operators

Tags: c++

I am facing a error when compiling my c++ code,
when hovering over it, it says error:-
no operator ">=" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::__cxx11::string >= intC/C++(349).

the code goes like this, its a function in a structure, which takes an array variable from the same structure and runs a loop to check the values in that array is greater or equal to 999,

**ERROR IS ON THE LINE - if ((PowerChecker.cpower[a] >= 999))
I AM NOT ALLOWED TO COMPARE ARRAY**

```
customers InputChecker(struct customers PowerChecker)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)
    {
        if ((PowerChecker.cpower[a] >= 999))
        {
            cout << "Please re-specify the power of your character" << PowerChecker.cpower[a] << endl;
            cout << "Power shoudl not Excced Limit 999 " <<endl;
        }
        
    }
    return (PowerChecker);
    
}
```

here is the image of error after compiling
[image: Image of error when compiled]

EDIT: SOLVED

Comment: What is cpower?

Comment: Seems like you are comparing a  some type of string with an integer. That won't work directly.

Comment: Apparently `PowerChecker.cpower[a]` is of type `std::string`.  `999` is of type `int`.  The error message is because a `std::string` and an `int` cannot be compared using a `>=` operator. You've incorrectly assumed that C++ works like some other language you know (e.g. interpret a string like `"123"` as a numeric value, so `"123" >= 999` has the same net effect `123 >= 999`).  You need to code to extract an integral value (if present) from the string before comparing.  And stop assuming your knowledge of other programming languages is relevant to C++ - C++ and other languages are *different*.

Comment: Did it not occur to you to share your definition of `customer:::cpowers` with us?

Answer (score 1):

As Peter and drescherjm wrote in the comments, it seems that you try to compare a string to an integer. You will need to convert the string first. Many ways how to do this can be found here: [How can I convert a std::string to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/how-can-i-convert-a-stdstring-to-int)