# stringstream in cpp is continual parsing possible

Tags: c++, string, split, stringstream

I've got a vector of strings wherein if the 1st character is "1" then I need to push the integer (represented as a string) into a vector else I just need to print the 1st char.
While using stringstream the following is the code ive written.

```cpp
vector<string> arr = {"1 23", "2", "1 45", "3", "4"};
vector<int> v;
for(string x : arr){
    stringstream ss(x);
    string word;
    string arr[2];
    int i =0 ;
    while(ss >> word){
        arr[i++] = word;
    }
    i = 0;
    if(arr[0] == "1")
        v.push_back(atoi(arr[1]));
    else
        cout << arr[0] << endl;
```

Instead of using an array arr, is there a way to take the next word from stringstream once the first word is "1"? Because when I tried the stringstream began all over again from start.

Comment: Use `ss >> word` once and inspect `word` before you do anything else?

Comment: atoi doesn't work with std::string. Would be glad if u added full working example with needed headers It could help run and debug.

Comment: So, you want 23 and 45 to end up in the vector of ints and 2, 3, and 4 to be printed out? If a string in arr is just "457" for example, do you really only need to print out the 4 in this case or are just just saying that strings that don't start with "1 " will only be a single digit?

Comment: yes ! 1, 2, 3 are basically the query numbers to identify the type of query.So they will be single-digit always

Answer (score 2):

The code uses `std::stringstream`, but it doesn't take any advantage from this object, like extracting directly an `int`.

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> arr = {"1 23", "2", "1 45", "3", "4"};
std::vector<int> v;

for ( auto const& word : arr )
{
    std::stringstream ss{ word };    // Initialize with a string,
    int first;
    if ( ss >> first )
    { // ^^^^^^^^^^^                    but extract an int...
        if ( first == 1 )
        {
            int second;
            if ( ss >> second )      // and another.
                v.push_back(second);
        }
        else
            std::cout << first << '\n';
    } // Error handling is left to the reader.
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I do not have enough reputations to upvote your answer

Comment: I was looking for this one! :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the strings are always well-formed and in the format you describe, and the numbers in the strings are always valid integers, you could so something like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const vector<string> arr = {"1 23", "2", "1 45", "3", "4"};
    vector<int> v;
    for (const string& s : arr) {
        if (s.size() > 2 && s[0] == '1' && s[1] == ' ') {
            v.push_back(atoi(s.c_str() + 2));
        } else {
            cout << s << "\n";
        }
    }
    for (const int i: v) {
        cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

For strings in the array that don't start with a 1 and a space that you said you're just supposed to print, I just printed out the whole string instead of its first character.

If you're not sure about your strings in the array, you'll need to check for errors first. Also, see [How can I convert a std::string to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/how-can-i-convert-a-stdstring-to-int) for alternatives to atoi().

Comment: I had not known about c_Str() earlier, This added to my learning.Thanks