# how to handle input type integer when we enter character c++

Tags: c++, integer, char

I have simple form and there is input type int. when i enter input `birthYear` and `currentYear` with character, the result is 0 and the program end before the input is filled.

```
char name[100], birthplace[100];
    int birthYear, currentYear, age;
    
    cout << "Name : ";
    cin.getline(name, 100);
    cout << "Birtyear : ";
    cin >> birthYear;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Current Year : ";
    cin >> currentYear;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Birthplace : ";
    cin.getline(birthplace, 100);

    age = currentYear - birthYear;
    
    cout << "=================" << endl;
    cout << "NAME : " << name << endl;
    cout << "AGE : " << age << endl;
    cout << "BIRTHPLACE : " << birthplace << endl;
```

i can't change the data type for `birthYear` and `currentYear` to string because it will be calculated.

i have try to convert change the data type for `birthYear` and `currentYear` to char and then convert it to int but when i enter character more than 1 the program not going well.

what i expect is when i enter character then the variable will set default value or the program show error message.

Comment: Read strings, then convert to integers. See [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction). It's about the free function `std::getline`, but it also applies to the member function `std::basic_istream::getline`.

Comment: @molbdnilo i use c++ version 8, so i can't use stoi

Comment: There is no version 8 of C++. Depending on your compiler, you might need to pass an explicit version to the compiler, such as `-std=c++11` for g++.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/how-can-i-convert-a-stdstring-to-int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When extracting an integer from an input stream, `operator>>` will put the input stream into an error state if the input can't be converted to an integer.  You need to check for this state and clear it before you can continue reading from the stream.  For example:

```
int readInt(const char *prompt) {
    int value;
    do {
        cout << prompt << " : ";
        if (cin >> value) break;
        cout << "Invalid number entered! Try again\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    while (true);
    cin.ignore();
    return value;
}

...

char name[100], birthplace[100];
int birthYear, currentYear, age;
    
cout << "Name : ";
cin.getline(name, 100);

birthYear = readInt("Birth Year");
currentYear = readInt("Current Year");

cout << "Birthplace : ";
cin.getline(birthplace, 100);

age = currentYear - birthYear;
    
cout << "=================" << endl;
cout << "NAME : " << name << endl;
cout << "AGE : " << age << endl;
cout << "BIRTHPLACE : " << birthplace << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `std::from_chars` (since C++17) to read a string and convert it to a number:

- `std::from_chars` allows you to check if the conversion from string to int had any errors (see return value `ec` in the example below), including extra characters (see return value `ptr`, pointing to the first character in the input string not matching an int).
- You can take the conversion code out to a function and use it both for the birth year and the current year.
- I would recommend using `std::string` instead of `char[100]` for reading input strings.
- I wouldn't recommend mixing `std::getline` and `cin >>`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/Erhqxq8Tz)

```cpp
#include <charconv>  // from_chars
#include <iostream>
#include <string>  // getline
#include <system_error>  // errc

int readYear(const std::string& text) {
    std::string yearStr{};
    int year{};
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << text;
        std::getline(std::cin, yearStr);
        std::cout << yearStr << "\n";
        auto [ptr, ec] = std::from_chars(yearStr.data(), yearStr.data() + yearStr.size(), year);
        if (ec != std::errc{} or ptr != yearStr.data() + yearStr.size()) {
            std::cout << "\tError: '" << yearStr << "' is not a correct year\n";
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return year;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Name : ";
    std::string name{};
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    std::cout << name << "\n";
    int birthYear{ readYear("Birth Year : ") };
    std::cout << birthYear << "\n";
    int currentYear{ readYear("Current Year : ") };
    std::cout << currentYear << "\n";
    std::cout << "Birth Place : ";
    std::string birthPlace{};
    std::getline(std::cin, birthPlace);
    std::cout << birthPlace << "\n";

    int age{ currentYear - birthYear };

    std::cout << "=================\n";
    std::cout << "NAME : " << name << "\n";
    std::cout << "AGE : " << age << "\n";
    std::cout << "BIRTHPLACE : " << birthPlace << "\n";
}

// Input:
//
//   John
//   abc
//   1980
//   2020def
//   2022
//   New York
//
// Output:
//
//  Name : John
//  Birth Year : abc
//      Error: 'abc' is not a correct year
//  Birth Year : 1980
//  1980
//  Current Year : 2020def
//      Error: '2020def' is not a correct year
//  Current Year : 2022
//  2022
//  Birth Place : New York
//  =================
//  NAME : John
//  AGE : 42
//  BIRTHPLACE : New York
```