# stof, stoi, stod vs extractor operator

Tags: c++, performance, type-conversion, precision

I was wondering which way is the most recommended one in modern C++ to convert a string to a number. Either double, float or integer.

I came across the C++11 `stof` but I have been using the extractor operator in `stringstream` instead within a helper function I created.
However, now with C++11 `stof`/`stoi`/`stod` exist. Therefor, should I stop using my helper function? I have tried researching the difference of both methods, but I cannot clearly see the pros and cons of them.

```
template <typename T>
bool stringToValue(const std::string& item, T& value)
{
  T tmp;
  std::istringstream iss(item);
  if ((iss >> std::dec >> tmp).fail())
  {
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    value = tmp;
    return true;
  }
}
```

I am also interested in keeping as much precision as possible.

Just to add, I found all the possible options here:
https://www.techiedelight.com/convert-a-string-to-a-float-in-cpp/

They are not compared in terms of efficiency or precision.

**NOTE:** I have seen `std::from_chars` used in C++17 with gcc 11 (I believe). We (My team and I) have recently moved to C++17, However, we are stuck at gcc 9.4.0. Therefor, we cannot use that one, sadly.

Comment: [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) is the hottest thing nowadays. All other alternatives have quirks (mostly incomplete input string validation, such as silently ignoring leading whitespace) that need to be worked around. Your implementation has the same issue, and additionally it ignores junk at the end of string.

Comment: Thank you. I added a NOTE to my post as I believe we cannot use that option currently. 
Too "modern" for my company. I recently pushed my company to upgrade to C++17 but we are still with Ubuntu 20.04 and gcc 9.4.0, which I believe does not include std::from_chars for floating points.

Comment: [`std::strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) & [`std::strtod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) and others are the next best thing. They need some manual work to do the right thing, so make sure to write a lot of tests for your wrapper (whitespace at the beginning of string, whitespace at the end, junk at the end, numbers being out of range in both directions (separately for signed, unsigned, and floating-point), etc).

Comment: Note that `std::from_chars` doesn't use locale if that's important to your application. The first question to ask is does the performance really matter? Is your program currently spending significant time parsing numbers? If not then stick with your already working solution. All the parsers have the same precision (they probably even call the same underlying conversion routines)

Comment: @AlanBirtles Off-topic: I don't remember a single time when locale-dependent number parsing was useful. The decimal point in my locale is `,` rather than `.`, but having a user-facing application only understand `,` is silly. The only sane option is to replace `,`->`.` before parsing regardless of locale (in user-facing apps), or just don't support `,` altogether (in text file formats). Microsoft tried to embrace the whole locale thing, and now Excel can't directly open CSV files in my locale, since they switch from `,` to `;` as field separator when `,` is already taken as decimal point.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I agree, everybody should just speak English it makes life much easier . CSV and other machine readable files definitely shouldn't be locale sensitive

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/7663709/5740428; but the answers there also don't really compare the different methods

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods of parsing numbers in C++. For a comprehensive comparison, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77079910/5740428).

In short, all the functions should offer the same degree of precision.
Chances are that they all use the same underlying routine for parsing floating point numbers at some point.

The main difference is the interface they provide, and what convenience/overhead that interface has. Some functions like `std::atoi` have terrible error handling and obscure names, but should be more efficient than streams due to not using locale features, and not using any dynamic polymorphism.

When in doubt, benchmark to compare their performance. There is no single function that is strictly better than all the others.

##### When (not) to use `std::sto*`

It's perfectly fine to use `std::sto*` family functions on their own, but they don't make for a good "fundamental utility" that is used everywhere in the project. They throw exceptions on failure, and "attempted parsing" where you're not sure whether the input is a number (i.e. failure is likely) would be slow because exception handling is very costly.

If you don't care and you just need something simple and safe (although not generic), `std::sto*` functions are fine.

##### The argument in favor of `std::istringstream`

Streams have high overhead and the header `<sstream>` is relatively large. They are really unattractive at first glance, but if your goal is to make a "universal parsing function", then streams make this easier than any other method because `>>` is supposed to work for everything.
You could keep using your current function.

However, if the include of `<sstream>` is too expensive, or you can't afford the run-time overhead that streams have, then you have to fall back onto the next best thing, the `std::strto*` family of functions:

```cpp
bool stringToValue(const std::string& str, long& out, int base = 10) {
    errno = 0;
    char* end = nullptr;
    out = std::strtol(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), &end, base);
    return str.data() != end && errno == 0;
}

bool stringToValue(const std::string& str, int& out, int base = 10) {
    errno = 0;
    char* end = nullptr; // note: there is no std::strtoi, so we use std::strtol
    out = std::strtol(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), &end, base);
    return str.data() != end && errno == 0;
}

bool stringToValue(const std::string& str, float& out) {
    errno = 0;
    char* end = nullptr;
    out = std::strtof(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), &end, base);
    return str.data() != end && errno == 0;
}

// ...
```

With templates, we could avoid copying and pasting an implementation for every single arithmetic type. However, it's still going to take a lot of effort to replace streams.